# How do I achieve this effect with css (image)

Tags: css, html

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViLYE.png)

So I have a div full of main article content with a width of 600px and I would like to have these links as well at the side, I imagine it would be in the same div but I can't seem to get the right effect and need some help with this.

Thanks a lot.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  <!-- viewport meta to reset iPhone inital scale -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>title</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="pagewrap">
    <div id="logos">
      <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <h1 id="name">Company Name</h1>
        <img class="socialmedia" src="img/facebook.png">
        <img class="socialmedia" src="img/twitter.png">  
        <img class="socialmedia" src="img/googleplus.png">    
      </div>
      <div id="header">
        <div id="menu-outer">
          <div class="table">
            <ul id="horizontal-list">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">eBooks</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</h2>
        <p id="article-information">posted on 15 May 2015 by <a href="#">Author</a></p>
        <img id="main-article-image" src="img/placeholder.png">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum. Integer
          fringilla. Integer fringilla. Pellentesque acturpis. Sed elementum, felis quis porttitor
          sollicitudin, augue nulla sodales sapien, amet posuere quam purus at lacus. Nam id neque. Morbipulvinar nulla sit amet nisl. Etiam pharetra lacus sed velit
          imperdiet bibendum. ed quis elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas
          justo. Donec interdum vestibulum libero. Nam laoreet dui sed
          magna. Nam consectetuer mollis dolor. Aenean ligula.
          liquam sed erat. Donec interdum vestibulum libero. Mauriset dolor.</p>
        <div id="more-links-list">
          <p>list</p>
          <p>items</p>
          <p>lol</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar">
      <h3>A guide to snoopsetting</h3>
      <img class="aside-images" src="img/placeholder.png">
      <h3>Welcome to the Surveillance State</h3>
      <img class="aside-images" src="img/placeholder.png">
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </bo
```

dy>

CSS

```
body {
  font: 1em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #669;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#logo {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  top: 50px;
}

#name {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 170px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 55px;
  height: 30px;
}

.socialmedia {
  position: relative;
  width: 8%;
  bottom: 155px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}

#main-article-image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
}

.aside-images {
  width: 340px;
  height: 255px;
}

#more-links-list {
  display: inline;
}
/************************************************************************************
STRUCTURE
*************************************************************************************/
#pagewrap {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 960px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#logos  {
  height: 160px;
}
#header {
  height: 50px;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
}
#more-links-list {
  float:right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background:#ddd;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 340px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 34px;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

#article-information {
  margin: 0px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 56px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 38px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 16.65%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

/************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

  #pagewrap {
    width: 94%;
  }
  #content {
    width: 65%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: 30%;
  }

}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  #content {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  #header {
    height: auto;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }

}

/* border & guideline (you can ignore these) */
#header, #content, #sidebar {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by placing a div with `float:right;` style inside the div that holds your content (article text), I created this example for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/davoscript/tjf56jLw/4/

```
<p>
    <!-- The floating box -->
    <div id="more-links-list" style="float:right;">
      <p>list</p>
      <p>items</p>
      <p>lol</p>
    </div>
    <!-- The article content -->
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum. Integer...
</p>
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: No this doesn't work, my div for my content is inside another div, every time I try to do what you put it goes below the text. I've edited my main post with my code

Comment: You have to put the div that represents the box, inside the parragraph that contains the text. I've updated the example with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/davoscript/tjf56jLw/4/

Comment: Awesome @M.Griffin, please remember to mark the answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put the links into an `<aside>`. This could go below the code for the text in your `div` and then styled with either a float or positioning. It would then be a matter of getting your styling to allow the text to wrap under the links.